# How to add Elasticsearch as a service in Ambari

Tags: elasticsearch

I was wondering to know how can I add Elasticsearch as a service to Ambari portal and monitor it through that portal? ... I know it's doable via Ambari Stacks, but I don't know how doing it. I found an RPM plugin, but since the host operating system is Ubuntu 14.0.3 it wouldn't work with that.

Answer (score 0):

There is a knowledgebase article on HDP website here:
https://community.hortonworks.com/repos/8630/ambari-elasticsearch-service.html

However, that article is nothing more than a link to a github project here:
https://github.com/Symantec/ambari-elasticsearch-service

This is an example of a custom stack that includes elasticsearch as a service. I know good answers here should be more than just links, but unfortunately in this case, this is the only set of resources I could find.